# How to install dependency scripts while installing an npm module

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

I have published an angular 2 library to npm recently.I have listed all the dependency scripts in the libraries package.json file. when I run `npm install my-library` all the dependency scripts are not installed.So, my question is how to install the dependency scripts while installing the library.

Comment: @Héctor that just installs a module and writes the package version to package.json.

Answer (score 0):

(This answer is valid for npm5+) In `package.json` you can specify 3 types of dependencies:

- `peerDependencies` - they are not automatically downloaded in any case ("good to have")
- `devDependencies` - which are downloaded when running `npm install` in the project itself, packages listed here are needed for development purposes only
- `dependencies` - which are downloaded on every `npm install` (also when adding your package to someone's project, "must-to-have")

Example:

```
{
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/core": ">=2.3.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~4.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.39",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.3",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "tslint": "^4.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.6.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.16"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ngx-store": "^1.2.2"
  }
}
```